# Numpy: divide the current row by the previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, dataframe

For my experiment, I have three different time-series data of the following format with different characteristics where the first column is timestamp and the second column is the value.

```
0.086206438,10
0.086425551,12
0.089227066,20
0.089262508,24
0.089744425,30
0.090036815,40
0.090054172,28
0.090377569,28
0.090514071,28
0.090762872,28
0.090912691,27
```

For reproducibility, I have shared the three time-series data I am using [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CoTiB3Tg_722OTc7Hum3hYOB3LLpfg7c).

From column 2, I wanted to read the current row and compare it with the value of the previous row. If it is greater, I keep comparing. If the current value is smaller than the previous row's value, I want to divide the current value (smaller) by the previous value (larger). Let me make it clear. For example in the above sample record I provided, the seventh row (28) is smaller than the value in the sixth row (40) - so it will be (28/40=0.7).

Here is my sample code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, acf


protocols = {}


types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time = []  
    col_window = [] 
    with open(fname, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        for i in reader:
            col_time.append(float(i[0]))
            col_window.append(int(i[1]))
    col_time, col_window = np.array(col_time), np.array(col_window)
    diff_time = np.diff(col_time)
    diff_window = np.diff(col_window)
    diff_time = diff_time[diff_window > 0] 
    diff_window = diff_window[diff_window > 0] # To keep only the increased values
    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "diff_time": diff_time,
        "diff_window": diff_window,
    }


# Plot the quotient values
rt = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(col_window)))

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time, col_window = protocols[protname]["col_time"], protocols[protname]["col_window"]
    rt = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(col_window)))
    plt.plot(np.diff(col_time), rt, ".", markersize=4, label=protname, alpha=0.1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.xlim(0, 0.003)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("difference")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

This gives me the following plots

[image]

[image]
[image]

However, when I do this

```
rt = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(col_window)))
```

It is dividing every current row by the previous row which is not something I want. As I explained above with an example in my question, I want to divide the current row value of column 2 by the previous value of column 2 ONLY if the current row value is smaller than the previous value. Finally, plot the quotient against the timestamp difference (`col_time` in my code above). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically need the `csv` module, I would recommend using the [`numpy` method `loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to load your files, that is

```
col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
```

This single line takes care of the first 8 lines of your `for` loop. Note the transpose operation (`.T`) is necessary to convert the original data shape (`N` rows by `2` columns) into a `2` row by `N` column shape that is unpacked into `col_time` and `col_window`. Also note that `loadtxt` automatically loads the data into `numpy.array` objects.

As for your actual question, I would use slicing and masking:

```
trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
decreasing_mask = leading_window < trailing_window
quotient = leading_window[decreasing_mask] / trailing_window[decreasing_mask]
quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_mask]
```

Then `quotient_times` may be plotted against `quotient`.

An alternative would be to use the [`numpy` method `where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to grab the indices where the mask is `True`:

```
trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds] / trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]
```

Keep in mind that all the above code still takes place in the first `for` loop, but now the `rt` is computed inside the loop as `quotient`. Thus after computing `quotient_times`, to plot (also inside the first loop):

```
# Next line opens a new figure window and then clears it
figure(); clf()
# Updated plotting call with the syntax from the answer
plt.plot(quotient_times,quotient,'.',ms=4,label=protname,alpha=0.1)
plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
plt.xlim(0, 0.003)
plt.title(protname)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("quotient")
plt.legend()
# You may not need this `plt.show()` line 
plt.show()
# To save the figure, one option would be the following:
# plt.savefig(protname+'.png')
```

Note that you may need to take the `plt.show()` line out of the loop.

Putting it together for you,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

protocols = {}

types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds] / 
    trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]
    # Still save the values in case computation needs to happen later 
    # in the script    
    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }
    # Next line opens a new figure window and then clears it
    plt.figure(); plt.clf()
    plt.plot(quotient_times,quotient, ".", markersize=4, label=protname, alpha=0.1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1.0001)
    plt.xlim(0, 0.003)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("time")
    plt.ylabel("quotient")
    plt.legend()
    # To save the figure, one option would be the following:
    # plt.savefig(protname+'.png')
# This may still be unnecessary, especially if called as a script
# (just save the plots to `png`).
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much and I have made your answer as an accepted. This is very short and precise! I have one more questions if I may - how can we load multiple (array of) filenames as I did in my question so that I can pass that to the `np,loadtxt()` function and plot them all at ones with respective labels as I did using the `for loop`?

Comment: it seems `loadtxt` works only with a single file, or am I wrong? I will be grateful if you could try iterate for multiple files (at least three as per the data I shared with my question).

Comment: @Brown, the `loadtxt` code provided above replaces the first 8 lines of the `for` loop, but not the loop itself. You'll still need to iterate over your `types` dictionary to read all the files.